# using timer to read file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, timer, desktop-application

i'm trying to parse a huge csv file in vb.net application but it gets stuck...i think using timer will be a good option but i dont know how to implement file reading through timer...can someone please guide me how to read a complete file through timer

Answer (score 1):

If by stuck, you mean that your GUI stops functioning, you should consider running your parse function on a background thread. This will keep your UI functioning while your file is parsed.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582) is an article about implementing async callbacks in .Net. It's actually written in C#, but hopefully you can translate it VB.Net.